# Javascript queries

Tags: javascript, html, child-nodes

I have been trying to practice some exercises using Javascript. Here are some challenges I have been facing. Please suggest if there is a mistake or something that I am missing.

> Note: I do not want to use Jquery at this stage.

Exercise:

Ask the user to input some text. On the click of a button, the entered text needs to be displayed as rotating.

1. The first approach I took gets me the result the first time. But if I enter a new text, and click the button, the rotation fluctuates between the old text and new. I am not sure if I am explaining it right. Here's the first attempt:

Test the result: http://learningharvest.co.in/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<p>Enter the text to be reversed</p>
<div id="texttoberotated">
<input type="text" id="texttobeRot"></p>
</div>
<div>
<button id="rotateText">Rotate Text</button>
<p id="rotatedText"></p>
</div>

<script>

document.getElementById("rotateText").onclick=function (){
var text=null;
text= document.getElementById("texttobeRot").value;
var finaltext=text;
document.getElementById("rotatedText").innerHTML=finaltext;
setInterval(rotatetext, 500);
var numberofRotations=0;
var length=0;
length=text.length;
var i=0;
function rotatetext(){
i=length;

if(numberofRotations<=text.length){

getText();
}else{
numberofRotations=0;
length=text.length;
i=length;
preText=null;
postText=null;
finaltext=null;
getText();
}
} 
function getText(){ 
preText=text.slice(length);
postText=text.slice(0,i);
i--;
finaltext=preText+" "+postText;
numberofRotations++;
length--;
document.getElementById("rotatedText").innerHTML=finaltext;
}
}

</script>
</body>
```

2. The second attempt I am making is using the childNodes method. However, I am unable to get the nodeValue of the input tag. The nodeValue is working if I try with any other element, but not with the input element.

Also, the function rotatetext is being executed on page load and not when the button is clicked. Works well if I add the onclick event inline in the button tag itself.

Here's the error i get in console:

> Rotate text parent child method.html:27 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeValue' of undefined
>       at rotatetext (Rotate text parent child method.html:27)
>       at Rotate text parent child method.html:23

Here's the body content I have drafted so far. At this stage, I am just trying to replace the text "Show Rotated Text here" with the text entered by the user.

```
<body>
<p>Enter the text to be reversed</p>
<input type="text" id="texttobeRot">
<button id="rotateText">Rotate Text</button>
<p id="rotatedText">Show Rotated Text here</p>
<script>
document.getElementById("rotateText").onclick= rotatetext();
function rotatetext(){
var element=document.getElementById("texttobeRot");
var textNode=element.childNodes[0];
var text=textNode.nodeValue;
var texttobeRotated;
texttobeRotated= text;
document.getElementById("rotatedText").innerHTML=texttobeRotated;
};
```

Look forward to all of your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Using the first approach if you add

```
  document.getElementById("texttoberotated").onkeyup = function() {
        text = '';
      }
```

to the bottom of your script it will clear the text value when you begin to type and you can enter a new word without the issue of them being jumbled together as you described.

I put a working example of your code at https://codepen.io/chaosmaths/pen/LrwrpQ